# Maui SQL Search page calling Grid page

Tags: c#, android, sql, .net, maui

I'm new to Maui. Originally from WinForms environment so very event orientated and having big issues wrapping my head around Maui, especially DI and MVVM.

So i'm trying to have a page accept a bunch of parameters and then display another page with a grid displaying all the returned records from an API. I've written and published the API, I've gotten each page working well individually I just can't get them working together.

The issue is I can't pass the parameters to the Grid page. The grid page has a BindingContext that gets the data to populate the grid but I can't find anywhere that I can access the calling pages parameters. In the below code I am passing the paramter class in the object from a button_click. I know this is bad in MVVM but it's familiar to me and I will tidy it up once working. I have got an MVVM version with the button binding to a method in the MV but reverted back to this way to try and solve the issue first.

I've created a parameter class and populated that with the fields from the calling screen but can't seem to access that before doing the API call.

```
    public partial class AnimalSearchNew : ContentPage
    {
        public AnimalSearchNew()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        async void OnSubmitClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AnimalParam animalParm = new AnimalParam();
            animalParm.AnimalName = "fred";
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new grdAnimal());
        }
```

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:dxg="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.DataGrid;assembly=DevExpress.Maui.DataGrid"
             xmlns:dxe="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.Editors;assembly=DevExpress.Maui.Editors"
             xmlns:dxc="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.Controls;assembly=DevExpress.Maui.Controls"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="True"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiAppPagesTest.AnimalViewModel"
             x:Class="MauiAppPagesTest.grdAnimal">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Grid" Order="Secondary" Priority="0" IconImageSource="dog_64_w.png" Clicked="GridClicked" />
        <!--IconImageSource=""-->
        <ToolbarItem Text="Grid Options" Order="Secondary" Priority="0"  IconImageSource="findperson_50_w.png" Clicked="GridOptionsClicked"/>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Map" Order="Secondary" Priority="0"  IconImageSource="mapicon.png" Clicked="MapClicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext >
        <local:AnimalDataViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <dxg:DataGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}"
                  EditorShowMode="DoubleTap"
                  AllowDragDropSortedRows ="True">
        <dxg:DataGridView.Columns>
            <dxg:TemplateColumn FieldName="Owner" Caption="Person" MinWidth="200"/>
            <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="Phone" MinWidth="150" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
            <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="Address" MinWidth="300" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
            <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="Tag" Caption="Tag" MinWidth="100" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="Tag_Expiry" Caption="Tag Expiry" MinWidth="150" DisplayFormat="d" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="Microchip_Number" Caption="Microchip" MinWidth="120" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="Name"  MinWidth="150" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="Breed"  MinWidth="150" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="Colour"  MinWidth="150" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="Gender"  MinWidth="100" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <dxg:CheckBoxColumn FieldName="Neutered" Caption="Neutered" MinWidth="100" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <dxg:CheckBoxColumn FieldName="Dangerous" Caption="Dangerous" MinWidth="110" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="BirthDate" Caption="BirthDate" MinWidth="150" DisplayFormat="d" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="DeathDate" Caption="DeathDate" MinWidth="150" DisplayFormat="d" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="DepartedDate" Caption="DepartedDate" MinWidth="150" DisplayFormat="d" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <dxg:CheckBoxColumn FieldName="CRM" Caption="CRM" MinWidth="100"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <dxg:CheckBoxColumn FieldName="Memo" Caption="Memo" MinWidth="100"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </dxg:DataGridView.Columns>
    </dxg:DataGridView>
</ContentPage>
```

```
    public class AnimalData
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Animal> Animals { get; private set; }
        public AnimalData()
        {
            GenerateAnimal();
        }
        void GenerateAnimal()
        {
            string Url = "https://{ValidAPI which returns data removed for security}/";
            IRequestHandler restSharpRequestHandler = new RestSharpRequestHandler();
            List<Animal> _animals = restSharpRequestHandler.GetAnimalByName(Url + "FindAnimalByName", "kito"); // AnimalParam.AnimalName);
            Animals = new ObservableCollection<Animal>(_animals);
        }
    }
```

I've searched a lot to find the correct way of doing this but can't find an example that has the same sort of page structure to me.

I just want to be able to tell a called page what to read from the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to pass parameter from `AnimalSearchNew` to page `grdAnimal` after triggering event `OnSubmitClicked`, right?
Then you can try to pass the parameter in the constructor of page `grdAnimal`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
private async void OnSubmitClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    AnimalParam animalParm = new AnimalParam();
    animalParm.AnimalName = "fred";
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new grdAnimal(animalParm));
}
```

In page `grdAnimal.xaml.cs`, you can get the parameter as follows:

```
public partial class grdAnimal : ContentPage 
{

      public  AnimalParam myParam { get; set; }

    public grdAnimal(AnimalParam param)
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.myParam = param;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That's what I had tried before. I was getting confused between the xaml BindngContext and the c# BindingContext. I didn't realize I could take the BindingContext out of Xaml and place it in c# after the initialiseComponent. I couldn't pass the parameters in xaml. Thanks Again :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking the ContentPage.BindingContext out of xaml and adding it with parameters after the initialiseComponent. Seems like a roundabout way of doing it but it seems to work. Now to make it proper MVVM :-(

```
    <!--<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:AnimalDataViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>-->

        public grdAnimal(AnimalSearch _animalSearch)
    {
        animalSearch = _animalSearch;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new AnimalDataViewModel(animalSearch);
    }
```